# Hide programs (such as Skype) from Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, skype, taskbar

I have my windows 7 taskbar with no pinned applications, and a quick launch.

Because I have windows set to show their title rather than just the icon they take up quite a bit of room.

I have skype open all day, and I cannot remove it from my taskbar, when I close the window it stays on the taskbar.

Is there a way to "minimise to tray" programs like this?

Comment: To close skype you have to either sign out, or open task manager and end it from there. I know this isn't your exact question but hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point is to keep Skype running...

Comment: Skype drives me crazy too. I like my taskbar clear so I can Alt+Tab efficiently. This isn't an exact answer to your question either, but I use Dexpot to work around this.

Comment: @r.tanner.f, I have used Dexpot in the past. I just want skype out of my Alt Tab, why can't it work like Google talk!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look under Tools menu > Options > Advanced for the relevant setting:

[image: Minimise Skype to tray while staying signed in]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks